# Transit at Bahrain for GCC Resident Permit Holder

Tags: transit, transit-visas

I am an Indian passport holder with Saudi Iqama. I plan to travel from Saudi Arabia to India with road transit through Bahrain. Khobar to Manama, Bahrain by SAPTCO Bus - Taxi to Airport - then Bahrain to India by Flight. Similarly for the return trip. Landing in Bahrain Airport and travel to Saudi by Bus.

I'd like to know:

What type of visa(s) I'd need to apply?

Should I need two visas (one for onward journey and other for return) ? -- considering that my stay in Bahrain both ways will be less than 4 hours.

Some comprehensive ideas please. I am open to other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are iqama holder i hope you no need any bahrain visa because you will get stamped on arrival 72 hours for 50sr at border while traveling.

Comment: One more question: Do SAPTCO drops passengers to bahrain airport still?